# Why doesn't an aliphatic acyl chloride react with cyanide ions in aqueous sulphuric acid undergo nucleophilic addition elimination?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm asking this because im proving a friend wrong. I get how cyanide ions won't react in an ethanol solvent because the solvent is too reactive but why won't this?[image]

Comment: How is your chloride turning into a methyl? Or did it just get cropped out of the picture? In general, compounds that look like (R)(R')C(OH)(X) are pretty unstable, where X is any kind of half-decent leaving group.

Comment: Thank you, I said the thing about it being unstable and tbf the chloride going to methyl went right over my head thank you. Going to go prove him wrong now.

Answer (score 1):

Cyanide ions in aq. sulfuric acid don't stay as ions very long, they get protonated to give HCN so cannot act as nucleophiles. Also aliphatic acyl cyanides are about as reactive as aliphatic acyl chlorides, both will readily hydolyse to the carboxylic acid in aq. soln.